# Hbase and Zookeeper

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

I have installed HBase 1.0.2, zookeeper-3.4.6, and java version "1.7.0_80"

```
Zookeeper works fine. But when i tried to start the shell of hbase ia m getting the following error. can anyone please help me out. I am really struct at this point.

The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.

my hbase-site.xml file is ,

<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///usr/local/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure zookeeper znode in hbase-site.xml.

```
<property>
   <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
   <value>/hbase</value>
</property>
```

The mismatch may be because of default configurations. You can verify the available znodes in ZooKeeper using zkcli.